# passing a dataframe of parameters to pmap (purrr)

Tags: r, purrr, pmap

Following the guidance in Hadley Wickams' [r for data science](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/iteration.html#mapping-over-multiple-arguments) , I want to pass a dataframe of parameters to a user defined function.

However, since the parameters are stored as characters within a dataframe ( df_params), I am having trouble with evaluation - in particular evaluating my df parameter. For example, here is a function:

```
`f <- function(df, group1, region1) {
        g1 <- as.name(group1)
        reg1 <- enquo(region1)
        x <- filter(df, (!!g1) == !!reg1) %>% select(country) 
       print(x)
    }
```

I have no problem passing f(df, 'group', 'region'). However, I want f('df', 'group', 'region') to evaluate 'df' as an object in my global environment instead of a character.

I am assuming(hoping) that by fixing this I will be able to pass

`df_params %>% pmap(f)`

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Try adding `get(df)` within your filter call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not provide data, so I created some fake data to demonstrate thie solution. What you are looking for is likely the `get()` function.

First for some fake data

```
> df1 <- data.frame(animal1 = rep(c('cat','dog'),5),
+                   animal2 = c(rep(c('cat','snake','dog'),3), 'dog'),
+                   country = c('USA','USA','USA','NK','NK','NK','NK','USA','MEX','MEX'),
+                   stringsAsFactors = F)

   animal1 animal2 country
1      cat     cat     USA
2      dog   snake     USA
3      cat     dog     USA
4      dog     cat      NK
5      cat   snake      NK
6      dog     dog      NK
7      cat     cat      NK
8      dog   snake     USA
9      cat     dog     MEX
10     dog     dog     MEX
```

This is your current function, which gives the output below:

```
> f <- function(df, group1, region1) {
+   g1 <- as.name(group1)
+   reg1 <- enquo(region1)
+   x <- filter(df, (!!g1) == !!reg1) %>% select(country) 
+   print(x)
+ } 
> 
> f(df1, 'animal1', 'dog')
  country
1     USA
2      NK
3      NK
4     USA
5     MEX
```

We can modify this by simply adding `get(df)` to your filter function. You can see it gives us the same output.

```
> f2 <- function(df, group1, region1) {
+   g1 <- as.name(group1)
+   reg1 <- enquo(region1)
+   x <- filter(get(df), (!!g1) == !!reg1) %>% select(country) 
+   print(x)
+ } 
> 
> f2('df1', 'animal1', 'dog')
  country
1     USA
2      NK
3      NK
4     USA
5     MEX
```

Comment: Many thanks Brandon for your comprehensive answer! Your solution works when passing the function with all parameters as strings. However, when passing `df_params %>% pmap(f) I get the error:              Error in (function (x, strict = TRUE)  :  the argument has already been evaluated

Comment: @northeastloon Ahhh I thought you were looking to evaluate the function using strings. It would be helpful if you could provide an example of the `df_params` data so that we can see that.

Comment: yes but these strings are stored in a dataframe - for example df_params <- expand.grid("df1", unique(df1$animal1), unique(df1$country). Anyhow, I tried again this morning from the company computer and everything works - i have no idea why I was getting the error mentioned below. Thanks!

Comment: I'm happy to hear it works now! @northeastloon Was my code useful or did you end up using the original code from your question?

Comment: Yes, it was useful and I used it. I upvoted but my reputation is not high enough for it to register.

Comment: @northeastloon Oh ok no worries. You can still accept it as an answer by clicking on the "checkmark", which should turn it green.